# Not able to restore SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Database backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 only. My system also has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed. On restoring that database it throws error:

> *The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.1600.*

What's the reason for this error. Please I need a solution

Comment: No, if you're running version 10.00.1600 you're running 2008, not 2008R2. [SQL Server Versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) has tables showing how version numbers correspond (once you move down past all the ways of finding version numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about the system you have. The error message clearly states that the current version is 10.00.1600, which is [SQL Server 2008 RTM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185). Your backup is indeed from a [SQL Server 2008 **R2**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185). You will only be able to restore that backup on an SQL Server 2008 R2.

Do not confuse the version of the tools (Management Studio) with the version of the SQL Server instance.

Comment: oh. thank you for your solution. K i will try to install sql server 2008 R2 properly

Answer (score 0):

Your backup source is created using sql server version `10.50.1600`, but your server is `10.00.1600` and like the error message said there is incompatible.

It is not possible to downgrade a database.
Possible solutions is to upgrade your instance from `10.00.1600` to `10.50.1600`.

If you're using SQL Express, you can download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25174).

Comment: i need a solution. What version and how i have to install